# Separating Data in Excel with formuals

Tags: excel, excel-formula, formula

I have to separate the following screenshot into the corresponding columns at the top.
I was able to figure out column D & F; however, I am having trouble separating the rest of the problem.

---

Constraint:

1. I cannot use the Text-To-Column format.
2. Zip codes must be 5 digits -> the leading 0 gets lost when string are translated to numbers
3. I need to use formulas along the lines of right/left/mid/find/search/etc.

---

The Role formula is:

```
  =MID(A2, SEARCH(",",A2) + 1, SEARCH(",",A2,SEARCH(",",A2)+1) - SEARCH(",",A2) - 1)
```

The City is:

```
  =LEFT(A2,FIND(",",A2)-1)
```

[image]

Comment: *Why* contrain yourself to not using the perfect tool for the job (text to columns)?

Comment: Why can't you use TTC? What about VBA? Otherwise it's similar formulas - what specifically is your problem with the others?

Comment: If you can only use formulas, `SUBSTITUTE` may be helpful to replace the nth comma instance, might make the overall formulas shorter.

Comment: I am not allowed to use TTC for the problem. I already asked if I could and they said no.

Comment: @sjr I am having trouble finding the right formula sequence past the second comma. I keep getting #VALUE or error messages

Comment: Use @BigBen's suggestion - SUBSTITUTE allows you to replace a specific instance of a comma with a # or similar unused symbol and then use SEARCH on that.

Comment: "I already asked if I could and they said no" - a bizarre prejudice against Excel tools?!

Comment: You can use number formatting to add the leading zero to zip codes.

Comment: @SJR along the lines of this: substitute(mid(substitute(A2,",",#),(",",A2,SEARCH(",",A2)+1) - SEARCH(",",A2) - 1) ?

Comment: You have to specify the instance. See shrivallabha.redij's neat answer.

Answer (score 3):

Equivalent formula of Text-To-Columns would be like below.

`=TRIM(MID(SUBSTITUTE(","&$A2,",",REPT(" ",199)),199*1,199))`

Depending on your requirement change number `1` in `199*1` by the field number i.e.

first field corresponds to 1

second field corresponds to 2

and so on...

Implement for the first data row and then copy down.

**Edit:**

If this data was to be sequentially split then following approach could have been easier instead of hard coded number...

`=TRIM(MID(SUBSTITUTE(","&$A2,",",REPT(" ",199)),COLUMNS($A$1:A$1)*199,199))`

Copy down and across!

** Edit2: **

For finding out first name and last name above formula will need addition of `LEFT` or `RIGHT` along with the same `SUBSTITUTE & TRIM` construct.

First name : `=TRIM(LEFT(SUBSTITUTE(TRIM(MID(SUBSTITUTE(","&$A2,",",REPT(" ",199)),3*199,199))," ",REPT(" ",199)),199))`

Last Name : `=TRIM(RIGHT(SUBSTITUTE(TRIM(MID(SUBSTITUTE(","&$A2,",",REPT(" ",199)),3*199,199))," ",REPT(" ",199)),199))`

*Assumes you have at least two words separated by one space minimum!*

Comment: Thank you! How do you recommend separating the first & last name in the columns because that one is separated by a space?

Comment: @pkchu95 are they always in `firstname lastname` format or you have `firstname middlename lastname` as well.

Comment: @pkchu95 I am signing out for the day and I have posted couple of formulas in edit2 which you can try for getting first name and last name.

Answer (score 0):

Not simple, but if you have Excel 2013+ with the `FILTERXML` function, you can use the following formulas:

```
First Name: =LEFT(FILTERXML("<t><s>" & SUBSTITUTE($A1,",","</s><s>") & "</s></t>","//s[3]"),
FIND(" ",FILTERXML("<t><s>" & SUBSTITUTE($A1,",","</s><s>") & "</s></t>","//s[3]"))-1)

Last Name: =MID(FILTERXML("<t><s>" & SUBSTITUTE($A1,",","</s><s>") & "</s></t>","//s[3]"),
FIND(" ",FILTERXML("<t><s>" & SUBSTITUTE($A1,",","</s><s>") & "</s></t>","//s[3]"))+1,99)

Role:  =FILTERXML("<t><s>" & SUBSTITUTE($A1,",","</s><s>") & "</s></t>","//s[2]")

Branch:  =FILTERXML("<t><s>" & SUBSTITUTE($A1,",","</s><s>") & "</s></t>","//s[6]")

City:  =FILTERXML("<t><s>" & SUBSTITUTE($A1,",","</s><s>") & "</s></t>","//s[1]")

State:  =FILTERXML("<t><s>" & SUBSTITUTE($A1,",","</s><s>") & "</s></t>","//s[4]")

Zip:  =TEXT(FILTERXML("<t><s>" & SUBSTITUTE($A1,",","</s><s>") & "</s></t>","//s[5]"),"00000")
```

- Using the commas to define the nodes, we create an XML
- We then use the position parameter `\\s[postion]` to decide which node to extract
- We also look for the `space` to separate the first from the last names.

  - As written, this will extract the first word as first name, and the second and any subsequent words as the last name.
  - *If you have entries with just a single name word, just modify the `$A1` in those two formulas to `$A1 & " "`*
- We also used the `TEXT` function to format the Zip as 5 digits.  If you have 5+4, you'll need to make the appropriate change in the format code.

[image]